# Is $x\mapsto (ax+b)/2^n$ in the affine groups of $\Bbb Z_2^\times$, $\Bbb Z_2$ and $\Bbb Q_2$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, p-adic-number-theory, affine-geometry

Is $x\mapsto (ax+b)/2^n$ in the affine groups of $\Bbb Z_2^\times$, $\Bbb Z_2$ and $\Bbb Q_2$?

Or what quantification of $a,b, n$ is necessary for $f$ to be the group of invertible affine transformations?

**My Attempt**

So I think for $\textrm{Aff}(\Bbb Z_2^\times)$ I need the bijections $f:\Bbb Z_2^\times\to\Bbb Z_2^\times$ in which case I need $a\in\Bbb Z_2^\times, b\in\Bbb Z_2\setminus\Bbb Z_2^\times, n=0$

In $\textrm{Aff}(\Bbb Z_2)$ it's less clear to me but there's more flexibility .  I think I need the injections $f$ such that both $f$ and $f^{-1}$ are onto $\Bbb Z_2$.  Tentatively therefore I think that I need $(ax+b):a\in\Bbb Z_2^\times, b\in \Bbb Z_2^\times$, correct?

Then in $\textrm{Aff}(\Bbb Q_2)$ it looks like there's a lot more freedom, in fact anything of the form $(ax+b)/2^n:a\in\Bbb Z_2^\times, b\in\Bbb Q_2, n\in\Bbb Z$.

Is that correct?  I feel like there should be a general rule for the affine transformations over the units, ring and field which instantly answers this question.

Comment: What is your definition of $\text{Aff}$ over the unit group? For example, what would $\text{Aff}(\Bbb Z^\times)$ be?

Over $\Bbb Q_2$ (since it is a field) an affine transformation is invertible whenever its linear part is invertible, so the only condition in our case is $a \not = 0$.

Comment: @Amateur_Algebraist it may not be well-defined over the unit group. I am very much a begginner at this so I'm trying to learn, and if you were to tell me it's only defined over the ring and field, I would not have much grounds to disagree with you. As far as I know, it's the group of invertible affine transformations so if there is a group of invertible affine transformations over the units, that would be it!  Off the top of my head, if you times by a unit and add a non-unit the transformation is going to to be closed in the units so that's where I was starting at.